# Is it possible to undo the software-removals committed by aptitude?

Tags: package-management, aptitude

In the beginning I had a problem installing VLC with apt-get, 
so somewhere here I found some one suggesting using aptitude instead of apt-get because it fixes some package problems with extra intelligence.

So I typed `aptitude install vlc` and I really did not read the things when aptitude asked me the (Y/N)-Questions.

While I meditated by watching the text raining inside the command line, I suddenly realized, that there were plenty of lines saying "removing xyz", among them important programs like cinelerra, kdenlive, lmms... basically most of the programs why I installed ubuntu suite 16.04.

After aptitude finished, I checked for the programs and they were really gone.

Now, here is the question: Is it possible to type some lines in the command line in order to undo aptitude's removals ?

Comment: Removing much of your system to install a non-Ubuntu version of VLC does not seem like a worthwhile workaround. Consider removing the non-Ubuntu sources and returning to as close at stock condition as possible to avoid many, many apt headaches later.

Comment: the funny and sad thing is VLC has not been installed at all :)